# bluej program for displaying following pattern for a school project

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, bluej

I have a fairly decent knowledge of Java in BlueJ programming environment. But I am at a loss to write a looping function to create this
pattern. Any help or pointers would be very helpful.

```
    1
    3 1
    5 3 1
    7 5 3 1
    9 7 5 3 1
```

My code thus far...

```
import java.util.*;
public class scanner {
    public static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val = 1;
        for( int i=1; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j > i; j--){
                System.out.print(j+" ");
                if(val != 1) {
                   System.out.print(1);
                }
                val +=1;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is too complicated. I suggest you define the key variables and use them for the algorithm. By the way, you don't need to use `java.util.Scanner` since you don't receive any input value from a console.

```
int end = 1;
int step = 2;
int rows = 5;

for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i+1; j++) {
        int number = end + i*step - j*step;
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output [(make sure](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/101566)):

```
1 
3 1 
5 3 1 
7 5 3 1 
9 7 5 3 1
```

Moreover, in your code you have the following line:

```
for (int j = 1; j > i; j--) { ...
```

This loop never allows entering its body because of the condition `j > i` and the `j` subtracting. I recommend you to debug your program and track the `i` and `j` values to understand what is going on.

Comment: Beat me by seconds!

Comment: he beat you by more than that but got the numbers wrong first ;)

Comment: Doesn't matter since your answer might be much better. I'd upvote it then.

Comment: @Mark: Yea, my previous (and deleted) answer had a wrong output indeed - it was wrong. This one is correct definitely.